# Bluemix and CMS (Joomla) and CF Push

Tags: joomla, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have installed a Joomla site with CF on bluemix.

As you know Joomla as other CMS allows to install components for adding functionalities.

This uploads the php code needed for the component and add additional tables/entries in the Database.

My issue is that when I CF PUSH, the new component script is removed from the joomla folders on bluemix, and the database still contains component's tables/entries.

I guess this is the situation for all CMS (Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla, Vbulletin, etc..).

How could I get a kind of CF PULL (?) to keep the modified CMS code including the new component locally on the computer side ?

So when i will redo the CF PUSH the installed component will not be erased.

Thank you in advance for your support,

Best regards

Yves

Answer (score 1):

There is no `cf pull` command in Cloud Foundry. The closest you would have is the `cf files app-name` command that you can navigate the directory structure of your cloud application and get specific files as needed, but this would be really tedious if you have multiple files to copy to your local computer.

It looks like Joomla fits better with the IBM Containers service in Bluemix. With the IBM Containers you can have an Docker image from Joomla (https://hub.docker.com/_/joomla/) and use persistent Volumes to save your added functionality. You can also use any Bluemix services (like a database) with IBM Containers.

The article below provides more details and step by step instructions to create an IBM Container for Wordpress. You can easily modify it for Joomla:

http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2015/05/22/wordpress-on-bluemix-containers/

Answer (score 0):

When you push an application on a runtime, php Java or whatever, it will restage all the application sources, included what has been configured and modified before through the cms interface, leaving the db databases untouched. And it is for joomla, but also for drupal or WP or any other cms. By this way to achieve what you wish you have 3 options:
- push exactly the filesystem structure you need on Bluemix, including the configuration files and modules to use on it
- use (as suggested above) a container instead of a runtime: anyway also with a container you have to install your cms on an external docker volume, otherwise the cms will be reset every time you restart the container
- use a Bluemix VM

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, and i started to use docker with two containers MariaDB and Joomla Images. First step in local my computer. The install Joomla starts well and the containers are linked,I just have the issue on the connecting the database, I put Localhost / root / database_Pwd. And the result is database not connected. I guess i missed one step. Best regards. Yves

Comment: Ok, I found my issue, the information to connect the database is in the logs of Joomla Container. :-) Then I have the joomla working on my local PC. Will push it to bluemix... for hosting, Thanks. Yves

Comment: I am very glad to know that it worked fine! PS could you accept the answer?